# When I try to write to a List my Previous text in there gets Overwritten

Tags: c#, linq

(The Books class is defined outside of this code.) So when I try to Read a book from this file I get only this one book. And every time I add a new one the old one gets over written. So I cannot add a new book to my myLibraryBooks List Because it gets overwritten automatically.

```
Books book = new Books();

Console.Write("Enter Author Name:");
book.Author = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter Book Title:");
book.Title = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter Book ISBN:");
book.ISBN = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter the Publish Date:");
book.Publish_Date = Console.ReadLine();

myLibraryBooks.Add(new Books() { Author = book.Author.ToUpper(), Title = book.Title.ToUpper(), ISBN = book.ISBN, Publish_Date = book.Publish_Date.ToUpper() });
Console.WriteLine("Book added Successfully");
sw.Write(book.Author, FILE_PATH);
sw.Write("\r\n", FILE_PATH);
sw.Write(book.Title.ToUpper(), FILE_PATH);
sw.Write("\r\n", FILE_PATH);
sw.Write(book.ISBN.ToUpper(), FILE_PATH);
sw.Write("\r\n", FILE_PATH);
sw.Write(book.Publish_Date.ToUpper(), FILE_PATH);
sw.Write("\r\n", FILE_PATH);
sw.WriteLine(book.Author, FILE_PATH);
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the problem in this code? Are you saying the `foreach` only occurs one time and you expect it multiple times?

Comment: No when I try to add a Book to my File it overwrites the one that is currently in there.

Comment: Could you show the declaration and the opening of `sw`? Something is missing here.

Comment: @Steve Defined outside of this code.

Comment: But it is declared as a StreamWriter?

Comment: Then, as I have said in my answer below, you need to open it using the constructor that accepts a boolean for append yes/no. The dafault one (just the filename) overwrites the previous file.

Answer (score 3):

I am supposing a lot here, but I wish to try to give an answer.

if `sw` is a StreamWriter (I can't see where is declared) then you should open it with

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("yourFile", true))
```

to force the StreamWriter to append to the current data and not overwriting it

[See MSDN StreamWriter constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx)

Also the `sw.Write` calls are wrong. You are using the overload that takes a format string and an object to be inserted in the format string. Instead you are simply writing the properties of the Books.

You should use

```
sw.WriteLine(book.Author);
```

to have each property on a separate line and not sticked togheter in one line.

Comment: +1 for seeing that without the OP posting the code, or even a clear question. -1 to the OP not reading documentation and providing bad example code..........